# Carousel is just uploading images to website without needing to change them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Guess this is a long one. I have seen [this bootstrap carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) on w3 and I'm trying to implement it on my website, but there seems to be a problem. Instead of working like on the ["Tryit Editor"](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h), the images are just being added to the website in a way that there's no image to slide to. They are just there, on the webpage, instead of being changed by each other. Hope I'm being clear enough.

Here's the code I pasted on the website. Please note that I have already put the tags on `head` to link to the w3 css and js page, and that I have already changed the image links to some of the images I want to be in the carousel.

```
<head>
    <!-- carousel head -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- carousel -->

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/foto1.jpg" style = "width: 100%;">
    </div>

  <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/foto2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/foto3.jpg">
    </div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the active class from second and third item div. And add another `</div>` before   `<!-- Left and right controls -->`.